# Handling left and right click at once in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouse, minesweeper

I'm making a Minesweeper clone in WPF (just a learning exercise). Those of you who have played Minesweeper before will know that if you press BOTH the left and right mouse buttons at the same time while the cursor is on a number, this will clear adjacent tiles given that the surrounding mines have been flagged.

Using the events provided by WPF, I can handle a left click or a right click, but not both at the same time. I was wondering if there is any proper way to take care of this other than setting variables for each button and turning them on/off with the appropriate down/up events.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check the state of the mouse buttons by the static properties in class [Mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.Mouse.aspx), like this:

```
if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
    Mouse.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's very close to what I want :) But I actually want to know when both left and right mouse buttons are pressed then released, i.e. a full click cycle on both buttons.

Comment: Then you need to handle the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events appropriately.